# Glue job error o90.getDynamicFrame: password authentication failed for user "glue"

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a daily Glue job that was working properly but suddenly stopped working a few days ago with this error:

> An error occurred while calling o90.getDynamicFrame. [Amazon] Invalid operation: password authentication failed for user "glue";

I'm using a glue context to create some dynamic frames from the catalog in this job:

```
   df_x = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database="xxx", table_name="xxx"
    ).toDF()
    
   df_xx = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database="xxx",
        table_name="xxx",
        redshift_tmp_dir="s3://xxx/xxx",
        additional_options={"aws_iam_role": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xxx"},
    ).toDF()
```

Do you have any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: ¿Can you please look if some of the tables have a specific "Connection" other than the standard S3 path?

Maybe one of the connections is using the user "glue" and the stored password is no longer valid.

Comment: Hey @JordiSabaterPicañol. Thanks for your answer. Exactly, the problem was with the connection to my second database that had the user "glue" but the password somehow vanished! I provided the password for the user and it worked :)